# Why is some information missing when cloning a DOM node?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dom

I am trying to clone a DOM node and add it to the dom with the original but with a few properties transformed.

I am working with Angular but I believe that should not be a factor in this as I am basically querying the DOM directly.

Here is my code for querying the DOM for the component, cloning it, and adding it back to the DOM in a new Absolute position.

```js
    const selector = `[hero-id='${heroId}']`;
    const component = this.document.querySelector(selector);
    console.log('The component HTML here is', component)

    if (component) {
      const rect: DOMRect = component.getBoundingClientRect();

      const { top, left } = rect;

      const newPosition = {
        left: (left || 0) + window?.scrollX,
        top: (top || 0) + window?.scrollY,
        height: component.clientHeight,
        width: component.clientWidth
      }
      console.log('The component textContent here is', component?.textContent)
      console.log('The component innerHTML here is', component?.innerHTML)
      console.log(`Returning`, JSON.stringify(newPosition))

      const newNode = component.cloneNode(true);

      this.renderer.setStyle(newNode, 'position', 'absolute');
      this.renderer.setStyle(newNode, 'top', `${newPosition.top}px`);
      this.renderer.setStyle(newNode, 'left', `${newPosition.left}px`);
      this.renderer.setStyle(newNode, 'width', `${newPosition.width}px`);
      this.renderer.setStyle(newNode, 'height', `${newPosition.height}px`);


      this.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(newNode)
```

But after doing this some of the information in the original component is missing in the Cloned component. Most importantly the text.

By reading through many articles this should be at the `textContent` or `innerHTML` property of the node. From the console logs we can see this is not the case.

[image]

I have not found a similar case and am wondering if what I could be doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: why do you not simply duplicate the component and usign ViewChild change the style and position?

Comment: @Eliseo I’m not sure what you mean but I think the reason is that this code is not actually part of a component but rather a directive.  what I am trying to do is create a Complex Animation. This code will be part of a directive that can be applied to a component of any type. It is unknown basically. It will have to copy the component of any type on the fly.